# Check if a channel has any messages Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to clear all the messages in a discord channel until it is completely empty.

My code:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'clearall',
    description: 'Clears ALL messages',
    async execute(message, args) {
        await message.channel.messages.fetch({
            limit: args[0]
        }).then(messages => {
            while ( <insert function here> == true) {
                message.channel.bulkDelete(100);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

(There is already some code in the main file (main.js) for invoking this file)

Comment: Why don’t you just clone the channel, and delete the old one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish that you can use the [`bulkDelete`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete) method from `TextChannel` like the following.

```js
async execute(message, args) {
    await message.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: args[0] })
        .then(messages => message.channel.bulkDelete(messages, true))
}
```

You start by fetching the channel messages and then call `bulkDelete` with those messages.
Notice that as stated in the [method description](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete) you can only bulk delete messages that are newer than two weeks otherwise you'll get an exception stating that. Therefore you can use the second parameter to filter those out (default is `false`).